# Message is encrypted with RSA 1024 public key A (from pair A1-B1). What is probability to decrypt with private key from different pair (A2-B2)?

Tags: rsa, ciphers

Our program encrypts the message with RSA 1024 public key A (from specific pair A-B). Then the program sends the encrypted message to the server. The server maintains a list of public-private key pairs {An-Bn} and the server iterates over this list of pairs and tries to decrypt the received message by every private key from the list. If the decryption succeeds then the server assumes that the message has been encrypted with the public key from this pair.

What is the probability that message, that is encrypted with the public key from one pair, can be decrypted by the private key from another pair?

The `decryption` in my question I define very widely as the success of the decryption procedure. This procedure is Delphi TurboPower LockBox2 `LbClass.TLbCipher.Decryptstring` in my specific case. But it can be `javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal` for Java/Android-Kotlin in other cases. My server is not inspecting the result of the decryption - it just execute the procedure and inspects if there is no non-empty result, irrespectively whether the result is some garbage or something meaningful.

So, if there is nonzero probability that the message can be encrypted with the private key from another pair, then our protocol can not perform.

Up to know we were not aware of this problem, we had some 300 pairs of keys and we used RSA 40 (very insecure indeed). Now we are migrating to the RSA 1024 and our tests show that there can be even some 20% rate. There are such public-private key pairs such that encyrption with the public key can be decrypted by very large number of private keys from other pairs.

We are using `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` for the encryption with the public key.